# Rails 5 includes and polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

I'm using Rails 5 and try to do next

```
class Song
  has_and_belongs_to_many :artists
end

class UnknownSong
end

class Library
  belongs_to :media, polymorphic: true

  belongs_to :song, foreign_key: :media_id, foreign_type: :media_type
  belongs_to :unknown_song, foreign_key: :media_id, foreign_type: :media_type
end
```

when I run this query

```
Library.includes(song: [:artists], :unknown_song)
```

rails generate next sql

```
SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."id" IN (391497, 921, 1469, 172)
SELECT "unknown_songs".* FROM "unknown_songs" WHERE "unknown_songs"."id" IN (391497, 921, 1469, 172)
```

and try to load different polymorphic models with same ids

```
data in database
```

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: What sql would you expect there?

Comment: `song` and `unknown_song` are defined _exactly_ the same (except for the name). So I don't see why/how it should use different ids.

Comment: I think foreign_type: :media_type base on polymorphic field "media_type" from database

Comment: add more explanation in description

Comment: Why use polymorphism in the first place? Why not just use one `songs` table  / model and use an enum to differentiate? It would spare you a bunch of headaches and potential performance issues.